# How can unzip data using vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, zip, gzip

I have data that is zipped using **zlib** in NodeJS. I need to unzip this data in vanilla js without using zlib. I have to use another library smaller than zlib if I must use a library to unzip.

I tried to unzip it with **pako.js** and **fflate.js** e.g.

```
var zippedData = '333080002363534b206588c43642621b23b14d90d8a6486c33181b00ccbe314454000000'
var buff = fflate.strToU8(zippedData)

var unzippedData = fflate.gunzipSync(buff)
```

If I run this code, it responds 'invalid gzip data'. Also, I tried these functions instead of **gunzipSync**. **decompressSync**, **unzlibSync** and the response is the same 'invalid zlib data' or 'invalid gzip data'

[image]

I can see my desired result if I add '1f8b0800000000000000' this 10 bytes to the beginning of zipped data and try to unzip with this tool [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/) that's in the pic.

Comment: Why not use `Transport-Encoding: gzip` header, and let the browser decode it for you? No need for a library.

Comment: There are many data in the response, not just that one. Also, I need to split it to get zipped data from the text

Comment: “I have to use another library” — Your question title says you have to use Vanilla JS, so which is it? Are you using Vanilla JS (which means *without any libraries*) or are you looking for a library recommendation?

Comment: Apologize for the uncertainty. I meant if there is a way to solve this unzipping issue without using any CDN library it will be better because I don't have enough memory for using a CDN library. If it's not possible and if I must use a library I can include a smaller one of around 40KB like fflate.min

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### I think there is a mistake in your zipped sequence

If it is supposed to be hexadecimal symbols, I would expect a mixture of about 6/16, i.e. 3/8's of the characters, being "a"-"f", but there are surprisingly few.

On the other hand, if it is supposed to be a string, it is even more unlikely that all characters are within 0-9 and a-f!

#### The first debugging steps I suggest are:

1. Verify that it is correct zipped output, i.e. demonstrate it being created from the input string by zlib? A screenshot would demonstrate it.
2. Verify that *zlib* can unzip it. If zlib zipped it but zlib cannot unzip it, nothing else will. A screenshot of zlib unzipping it would convince me.

I do think the original zipped sequence is not correct.

#### If your zippedData is supposed to be data that has *already* been zipped, why are you passing it in to `fflate.strToU8`, whose purpose is to Zip a string?

From https://github.com/101arrowz/fflate

```
Using strings is easy with fflate's string conversion API:

const buf = fflate.strToU8('Hello world!');

// The default compression method is gzip
// Increasing mem may increase performance at the cost of memory
// The mem ranges from 0 to 12, where 4 is the default
const compressed = fflate.compressSync(buf, { level: 6, mem: 8 });

// When you need to decompress:
const decompressed = fflate.decompressSync(compressed);
const origText = fflate.strFromU8(decompressed);
console.log(origText); // Hello world!
```

Comment: Yes, I'm sure this one correct zipped output and I want to get the result that is in the pic using fflate if it is possible. Actually, it zipped using zlib but I can not use zlib for js because of the device's memory. That's why I'm looking for other solutions.

Comment: Those three suggestions were not to solve your original problem, but to debug your solution which is not working. Doing those steps will help you _understand_ what has gone wrong. Can you show screen shots of evidence for the first two?